# Gnome Backups (DejaDup) Flatpak version suddenly unable to open paths

Tags: flatpak, project-atomic

### Intro

I had a fine run using Gnome Backups (DejaDup) Flatpak version as my backup solution until today, when the software refuses to use paths located in my HOME directory saying that:

> This folder cannot be backed up because Backups does not have access to it.

Access is given through Flatseal to the whole HOME dir as well as to these separate dirs, but to no avail. Some of these directories are Unicode (Cyrillic), some are pure Latin and common system paths (i.e. ~/Music/ or even xdg-music).

I first thought that I had an issue with my locale, but it doesn't seem like it (or maybe I'm wrong?).

Layered (non-Flatpak) DejaDup is working, but I REALLY prefer to use the Flatpak version so I don’t have to layer anything through rpm-ostree.

Flatpak version: 1.15.6

Linux distribution version: Fedora Kinoite 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64 (KDE Plasma)

#### How to reproduce

1. Add any backup path in HOME or elsewhere.
2. Try to commence backup.
3. Get message: "The following folders cannot be backed up because Backups does not have access to them: [listed dirs]"

#### Expected Behavior

GNOME Backups to be able to access any directory in HOME or any other user-created directories (incl. those on other mounted drives).

Flatseal or `flatpak override` to be able to allow filesystem access.

#### Actual Behavior

GNOME Backups cannot access any directory in HOME or elsewhere. Simply states: "This folder cannot be backed up because Backups does not have access to it".

Flatseal or `flatpak override` 'allow' filesystem access, but GNOME Backups is still unable to use it.

### Locale stuff

`flatpak run --command=locale org.gnome.DejaDup` used to print this (BTW the same is printed for VLC, Flatseal):

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_TIME="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_PAPER="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_NAME="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="xx_XX.utf8"
LC_ALL=xx_XX.utf8
```

but was repaired with `flatpak config --set languages en` to:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

System-run locale command gives:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Also tried changing all settings in System settings → Region & Language to defaults, modified a few system files (e.g. /etc/locale.conf), etc… ran flatpak repair, trying to solve the issue. Nothing helps.

Running `flatpak run org.gnome.DejaDup` produces:

```
Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

### Inconsistency with applied permissions

Weirdly enough, it seems that Flatseal applies permissions *for itself and for KDE*, but they don’t apply to DejaDup. I can see them ‘applied’ from both within Flatseal and KDE settings → Flatpak permissions, but when I try `flatpak permission-show org.gnome.DejaDup` there’s nothing printed. When I also try `flatpak override --show org.gnome.DejaDup` nothing is printed. `flatpak repair reinstall-all` didn’t fix the issue as well.

### Wrap up

It seems as if DejaDup is living in a separate reality from the system, and refuses to accept new permissions. Even when I reset them through Flatseal, or `flatpak override --reset org.gnome.DejaDup` (which should in theory allow ‘All system files’ access to the app), it still cannot access any directory that I choose.

I also rebooted my whole system a good deal of times between all these changes.

What is going on?!

### Post scriptum

P.S. GNOME Backups and Flatseal are installed as system Flatpaks, not user ones: `flatpak list --system` prints them out, `--user` doesn't.

### Some background info

I am more than 90% certain that this is a Flatpak-cum-system issue, not with the specific app. The reasoning behind this is:

1. I actually had GNOME Backups Flatpak version working two days ago, without any issues (albeit I changed/updated *something* since then, but I fail to see what could have been so radical of a change to create this mess;
2. I notice some issues with how permissions/overrides are set (inconsistency), which are Flatpak-dependant (see below);
3. The non-Flatpak version works just fine, but I prefer the Flatpak one;
4. There are users with similar/same issue but for different apps, or altogether all Flatpak apps: (example: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/flatpaks-cant-seem-to-access-most-folders-including-home/76543/4);
5. This (https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/113) issue ticket is similar and old, and supposedly 'solved', but it is not solved for me;
6. I am at the end of my wits here (while being a relative Linux newbie).